# How to define the JSON structure for any incoming flow file in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need to define the structure of JSON for all my incoming flow files. I have a JSON which is like this,

```json
[
  {
    "user": "Tony",
    "dept": "Sales",
    "os": "linux"
  },
  {
    "user": "Smith",
    "os": "Windows",
    "dept": "Accounts"
  }
]
```

I want all my files of JSON to have a uniform structure sorted, eg. in the input my field positions are different for first object and second object. In the input the order we see is

```json
{ "user" , "dept" , "os" } , { "user", "os", "dept" }
```

I want my output to be

```json
{ "user" , "dept" , "os" },  { "user" , "dept", "os" }
```

Need help doing this in Nifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation spec by individually writing each attribute in order to sort them as desired such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "user|dept|os": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros Özhan for your solution but, I don't want all my values to map to a same field (Key). I want individual objects to be returned in a defined format, I need help on that. I'm sorry for the confusion in my question. I want the JSON to be returned as this                         {
  "user": "Tony",
  "dept": "Sales",
  "os": "linux"
},
{
  "user": "Smith",
  "dept": "Accounts",
  "os": "Windows"
}

Comment: In the input my field positions are different for first object and second object. In the input the order we see is { user , dept , os } , {user, os, dept} I want my output to be        { user , dept , os },{ user , dept , os }

Comment: @Ram I've just edited, are you able to check it out

Comment: Thanks @ 
Barbaros Özhan
for this method its working fine and sorry for the delay in reply.

Comment: @Ram, could you mark the answer as accepted please. It would help the community and also the contributor of the answer.